# An easy way to count sum of squares of first x prime numbers?

Tags: prime-numbers

> I want to count sum of squares of first $x$ prime numbers.
>   $$1^2+2^2+3^2+5^2+\ldots +p_x^2$$ 
>   Is there a formula to do it? (like the formula to count the sum of squares of  natural numbers)

Comment: I do not think so, we do not even have a formula to generate prime numbers.

Comment: Probably not. We don't have a formula for finding out the $n^{th}$ prime yet and this depends on that. However I can think of a few non-explicit formulas that might work but require more computations.

Comment: and $1$ isn't even a prime

Comment: See [OEIS sequence A024450](https://oeis.org/A024450).

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan More explicitly, if there were a formula $f(n)$ for the sum of the first $n$ prime numbers squared, then $\sqrt{f(n)-f(n-1)}$ would be a formula for the $n$th prime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no closed form of the sum of primes or prime powers. The best we have is an asymptotic formula. Rafael Jakimczuk has given the asymptotic sum of prime powers in the paper below so you can estimate of the sum of the squares of primes.

[Theorem 2.1 in Sums of Primes An Asymptotic Expansion](http://www.m-hikari.com/ijcms/ijcms-2014/13-16-2014/jakimczukIJCMS13-16-2014-2.pdf)