# A Number Theory problem on AoPS Alcumus

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For positive integer $n$ such that $n < 10000$, the number $n+2005$ has exactly 21 positive factors. What is the sum of all the possible values of $n$?

Given that $n + 2005$ has $21$ positive factors, $n + 2005$ can be written as $p_1^2 \cdot p_2^6$ because $(2+1)(6+1) = 21$. Also, $n + 2005$ must be greater than $2005$ and less than $12005$ because $0 < n < 10000$. My plan was to sum up the possible values of $n+2005$ and then subtract $2005$ times the number of possible values. But this seems to be quite hard since for example, let $p_2 = 2$, then $p_2^6$ = 64, and then there are many squares of prime numbers that can be $p_1$. When I searched up "Sum of prime squares", it showed [An easy way to count sum of squares of first x prime numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3209788/an-easy-way-to-count-sum-of-squares-of-first-x-prime-numbers) as one of the results. It says that there is **no closed form** on the accepted answer, or no exact expression. So I have to brute out the squares and add them one by one, which isn't a good idea. Is there an easier way (answer is probably yes)? What is it?

Comment: Isn't there a designated place on AoPS to ask alcumus questions?

Comment: I'd say the method you started looks optimal.  Note that many $p_1$ work here....

Comment: Given that $5^6 = 15625 > 12005$, $2^6\cdot16^2  = 16384 > 12005$, and $3^6\cdot 5^2 > 720 \cdot 25 = 18000 > 12005$ there's not too many cases to check.

Comment: @AlanAbraham, there is an Alcumus forum, but usually it doesn't work for me.

Comment: $p_2$ can only be $2$ or $3$. If $p_2 = 2$ then $p_1 = 7, 11, 13$. If $p_2 = 3$, then $p_1 = 2$.